# UWP include/require XAML as in PHP

Tags: xaml, uwp, include, uwp-xaml

So I've been struggeling with this really badly and I don't understant any of the found "answers"... I have a menu which I want to use on multiple pages, but not all of them. So I have an "index" page with a splitview in it, to have a menu on the side and the content on the right. But I want to be able to "include" the menu, to be able to edit just one file and not to write in every page the menu again... Below you can find my code of one page;

```
<Page
    x:Class="RittensportRekenSoftware.Views.Index"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:RittensportRekenSoftware.Views"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}" RequestedTheme="Dark">

    <SplitView x:Name="MySplitView" DisplayMode="CompactOverlay" IsPaneOpen="False" CompactPaneLength="50" OpenPaneLength="150">
        <SplitView.Pane>
            <!-- Here will the menu be included, so we don't have to re-render it every time again and it's changeable from withing one file -->
            <StackPanel Background="#202225" RequestedTheme="Dark">
                <Button x:Name="HamburgerButton" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Content="&#xE700;" Width="50" Height="50" Background="Transparent"/>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Button x:Name="MenuButton1" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Content="&#xE825;"
                    Width="50" Height="50" Background="Transparent"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="Button 1" FontSize="18" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Button x:Name="MenuButton2" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Content="&#xE10F;"
                        Width="50" Height="50" Background="Transparent"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="Button 2" FontSize="18" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Button x:Name="MenuButton3" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Content="&#xE1D6;"
                        Width="50" Height="50" Background="Transparent"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="Button 3" FontSize="18" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                </StackPanel>
            </StackPanel>

        </SplitView.Pane>
        <SplitView.Content>
            <Grid>
                <TextBlock Text="Content here :D" FontSize="54" Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            </Grid>
        </SplitView.Content>
    </SplitView>

</Page>
```

Now, It would be great to have something like "include menu" that gets the content from a file in `Views.Layouts.Menu.xaml`, except I have no idea how such file should be made and how to include.

Kindest regards

Robin

Comment: Check out UserControls. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.usercontrol

Comment: Yes, I have seen that, but I don't understand anything of it....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now, It would be great to have something like "include menu" that gets the content from a file in Views.Layouts.Menu.xaml, except I have no idea how such file should be made and how to include.

Making a UserControl was on the right dirction. Please follow my following step to have a try:

1. Right click your project - Add - New Item - Select `User Control`

[image]

2. Copy your code into this UserControl XAML page like the following:

   ```
   <UserControl
   x:Class="AppSplit.MyUserControl1"
   xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
   xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
   xmlns:local="using:AppSplit"
   xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
   xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
   mc:Ignorable="d"
   d:DesignHeight="300"
   d:DesignWidth="400">

   <SplitView x:Name="MySplitView" DisplayMode="CompactOverlay" IsPaneOpen="False" CompactPaneLength="50" OpenPaneLength="150">
       <SplitView.Pane>
       <!-- Here will the menu be included, so we don't have to re-render it every time again and it's changeable from withing one file -->
           <StackPanel Background="#202225" RequestedTheme="Dark">
               <Button x:Name="HamburgerButton" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Content="&#xE700;" Width="50" Height="50" Background="Transparent" Click="HamburgerButton_Click"/>
               <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                   <Button x:Name="MenuButton1" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Content="&#xE825;"
               Width="50" Height="50" Background="Transparent"/>
                   <TextBlock Text="Button 1" FontSize="18" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
               </StackPanel>
               <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                   <Button x:Name="MenuButton2" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Content="&#xE10F;"
                   Width="50" Height="50" Background="Transparent"/>
                   <TextBlock Text="Button 2" FontSize="18" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
               </StackPanel>
               <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                   <Button x:Name="MenuButton3" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Content="&#xE1D6;"
                   Width="50" Height="50" Background="Transparent"/>
                   <TextBlock Text="Button 3" FontSize="18" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
               </StackPanel>
           </StackPanel>

       </SplitView.Pane>
       <SplitView.Content>
           <Grid>
               <TextBlock Text="Content here :D" FontSize="54" Foreground="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
           </Grid>
       </SplitView.Content>
   </SplitView>
   </UserControl>
   ```

```
public sealed partial class MyUserControl1 : UserControl
{
    public MyUserControl1()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void HamburgerButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MySplitView.IsPaneOpen = MySplitView.IsPaneOpen == true ? false : true;
    }
}
```

3. If you want to include this UserControl on other XAML pages, you could do like the following:

   ```
   <Page
   x:Class="AppSplit.MainPage"
   xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
   xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
   xmlns:local="using:AppSplit"
   xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
   xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
   mc:Ignorable="d"
   Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

       <local:MyUserControl1></local:MyUserControl1>
   </Page>
   ```

Comment: Yes, but I only need the menu, so I have made a file in Views.Layouts with the name `Menu`, but if I do `<local:` it never gives me the option to include that file (which is only the Splitview pane content) So what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: If your `Mean` control is in 'ViewsLayouts\Menu.xaml' directory, you need to add namespace to it like this `xmlns:layout="using:your project name.Views.Layouts"`, then you could include this control `<layout:Menu></layout:Menu>`.

Comment: And how should I create the toggle function then? Because it toggles the splitview in the other file.

Comment: @Robin What did you mean about 'toggle function'? I did not understand what you say 'it toggles the splitview in the other file.'.

Comment: Well, you can "toggle" the menu to collaps or open. Now, that code is C# and originally is in the c# code of the "splitview" xaml property. Now, you have to do that toggle action on the splitview, but there is no reachable code then

Comment: It's a UserControl. You could make the menu collaps or open in `UserControl.xaml.cs`. You just need to register click event for 'HamburgerButton' and handle it in `UserControl.xaml.cs`. See my edited reply.

Comment: Well, I noticed that you seem not be familiar with UWP.  I suggested that you could  read the document from [start](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/get-started/). You need to know many things. For example, XAML layout, controls etc.